# Why do the same operations on numpy and python list get different results?

Tags: python, list, numpy

I try to replace the value of the first element with the value of the second element on a numpy array and a list whose elements are exactly the same, but the result I get is different.

1) test on a numpy array:

```
test=np.array([2,1])
left=test[:1]
right=test[1:]
test[0]=right[0]
print('left=:',left)
```

I get: `left=: [1]`

2) test on a python list:

```
 test=[2,1]
 left=test[:1]
 right=test[1:]
 test[0]=right[0]
 print('left=:',left)
```

I get: `left=: [2]`

Could anyone explain why the results are different? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please reformat code block for readability. Use code block icon in formatter, or back quotes.

Comment: @kcw78, thanks for your suggestion. This is the first time I post a question on stack overflow so I don't know much about the format issue. I have revised the format of the code and hope it is easier to read now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Slicing (indexing with colons) a numpy array returns a view into the numpy array so when you later update the value of test[0] it updates the value of left as left is just a view into the array.

When you slice into a python list it just returns a copy so when you update the value of test[0], the value of left doesn't change.

This is done because numpy arrays are often very large and creating lots of copies of arrays could be quite taxing.

Comment: Thanks a lot, James. Now I understand it.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on James Down explanation of numpy arrays, you can use `.copy()` if you really want a COPY and not a VIEW of your array slice. However, when you make a copy, you would have to do the copy of left again after reassigning `test[0]=right[0]` to get the new value.

Also, regarding the list method, you set test[0]=right[0], so if you `print (list)` after the assignment, you will get `[1 1]` instead of the original `[2, 1]`. As James pointed out, `left` is a copy of the list item, so not updated with the change to the list.

Comment: Thanks @kcw78. I came across this problem when I tried to implement the merge sort algorithm on a numpy array and it didn't work. But when I tried to add .copy() when slicing the list it worked. So I thought about the root of the problem. Actually I read in the book 'Python for data analysis' that the slice of a numpy array is just a view of it, but  I don't really understand it until James and you pointed it out for me. Thank you all again.